# Oracle Coherence write-behind cache and manual DB update

Tags: java, database, oracle-coherence

Say I have a write-behind cache in Oracle Coherence, with data initially loaded from the DB.
I remove some rows from DB manually.

Then I gracefully stop the Coherence server. Pending writes will be persisted, I know that.

The question is: if there was no modification on an object, would Coherence persist it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Coherence only persists data that has been modified (e.g. via a put()) by the application. If you need to modify the data without it being written back to the database, I believe you need to signify the update as being a "synthetic" update via an EntryProcessor and the BinaryEntry interface.